# IBM Connections Blog recommend API

Tags: api, ibm-connections

I am working on Blog APIs of IBM connections 3.0
From IBM Docs I got details about how I can recommend a blog entry and how I can get list of peoples recommended blog entry.

I Need API details, how I can undo my recommendation for particular blog.

In web IBM connections is calling /blogs/roller-services/json for the this action which requires "dangerousurlnonce" to be posted, I could not find, how I can get the value for "dangerousurlnonce" either.

-- Vishal

Comment: you can definitely look at https://greenhouse.lotus.com/sbt/SBTPlayground.nsf/Explorer.xsp#api=Social_Blogs_API_Working_with_recommendations if the method is a put, you can do a put to create, or delete to remove (just a few thoughts)

Comment: thanks for your comment, but the method is post, actually as per documents its blank post to a URL. I tried to use DELETE method, but got error for it.

Comment: have you tried with 4.5?

Comment: we have setup for 3.0 only :( will try with 4.5

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'blogs/roller-services/json/authcheck?entry=' + entryId,
    success : function (data) {
    // yes we need to use dojo here as the response is invalid json that only dojo can parse
        dangerousurlnonce = dojo.fromJson('{' + data + '}').nonce;
    }
});
```